# How to ignore error while running r script

Tags: r

I have a R script where some of scripts not run sometimes because of data unavailability. I want to ignore this error so that my script can run on cron schedule.

Script:

```
data1 = data1 %>% mutate(`04_Days`=paste(round(ifelse(`04 Days` %in% c(NA,"NA"),0,`04 Days`)/`Till date attempted1`*100,0)," %"))
```

where sometimes the variable `04_Days`is not available and I want to ignore this error while running this line.

Comment: By not available, do you mean that nothing is assigned to the variable `04_days`, meaning you get a error, that it does not exist? And what package does the `mutate` function come from?

Answer (score 2):

You can use tryCatch as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r/12193902#12193902).

If the code inside tryCatch throws an error, the error function is called. If you want to ignore the error, just leave that function empty.