# How can I get RStudio to continue executing code after encountering an error

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using RStudio on Mac and like to highlight a chunk of code and hit `Command + Return` to get this chunk to run. For some reason, when I do this now, the code stops running when an error appears. How can I get it to go back to the way it used to be when all of the lines would run even if a previous line returned an error?

Answer (score 4):

In case this helps anyone who comes to the page, this was due to a change in the default behaviour by RStudio. The issue was raised and discussed [on github](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10391).

They've added a checkbox to return to the old behaviour in the new [daily builds](https://dailies.rstudio.com/). After installing the latest version you can go to Tools - Global Options - Console, and then uncheck "Discard pending console input on error".

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of: [How to ignore error while running r script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050798/how-to-ignore-error-while-running-r-script).

The easiest method is to use the [`tryCatch()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.oo/versions/1.2.7/topics/trycatch) function. As explained in detail here: [Debugging, condition handling, and defensive programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html)

A good example of the syntax is given here: [How to write trycatch in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r/12193902#12193902). As shown:

```
result = tryCatch({
    expr
}, warning = function(warning_condition) {
    warning-handler-code
}, error = function(error_condition) {
    error-handler-code
}, finally={
    cleanup-code
})
```

You can test it like this:

```
result <- tryCatch({1==0}, error=function(e) e)
if (inherits(result, "error")) {
  print("There was an error")
} else {
  # pass through, there was no error.
}
```

Here is a good example of how to implement this `tryCatch()` in to a function: [github/cran/seastests/R/qs.R](https://github.com/cran/seastests/blob/master/R/qs.R).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your shortcut may be bound to the `source` execution method, which executes the file as a whole, instead of the interactive `run`. You may need to [check or update your shortcuts](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts-in-the-RStudio-IDE).